# enable to add bootstrap glyphicons to input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm not able to add a bootstrap glyphicons to

```
<form role="form">
 <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
    <i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
 </div>
</form>
```

capture

http://goo.gl/ibE2sn

Comment: Hmm... Seems to be working as intended here: http://www.bootply.com/0NkRufA3Ud Can you post your HTML (from `<body>` to `</body>`)? And sorry, image didn't download for me last time, but I see the issue isn't in the folder structure, so I removed that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is working as intended. Both of these examples work, so perhaps it's somewhere else in your code?

The 2 ways to add glyph icons:

```
 <i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
```

and

```
<span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```